# How to pass the textbox text to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a simple text box, a button and an `a` element and I am trying to write a website URL and I need to pass this URL to `a` element.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<a id="weburl" href="http://jquery.com/"></a>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
```

If I click the button I need to take the text from the textbox and I need to pass to the href tag, how can I do this?

I am facing a problem still with this as shown below:

1.If I mentioned the URL in the href tag And If I give another URL in the textbox and then If I click the button it is showing me the different URL's as shown below:

[image]

2.And If I remove the URL and give some other URL in the textbox and clicks the button it is not showing me anything except a blank page.

While debuggin I have seen that it is showing me the value of textbox what I gave and the URL I mentioned in the href tag as shown below:

[image]

[image]

And I need both to be equal as I do not want the href to be mentioned in the href tag I want to do it programatically as james said.

Comment: What is it...do you want it in javascript/jQuery or asp.net?

Comment: I need to pass the text using javascript.As I am using Asp.Net so I have mentioned the tags.

Comment: I dosen't know how to pass it so I wanted to know.And I have used document.getElementById but its giving me an error as there is nothing   in the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#TextBox1").change(function() {
    $('#weburl').attr('href', $(this).val());
});
```

To clarify you server control client id you may use:

```
$('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: @Thanks Samich for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

**Pure JS:**

```
function GetURL()
{
    var myAnchor = document.getElementById("weburl")
    var myTextBox = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>")
    myAnchor.href = myTextBox.value;
}

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="GetURL(): />
```

**jQuery (using button click event):**

```
$('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function() {
    $('#weburl').attr('href', $(this).val());
});
```

**jQuery (using text box change event):**

```
$('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').change(function() {
    $('#weburl').attr('href', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @Thanks James Hill for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like.

```
 $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click({
     $('#weburl').val($('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').val()); 
 })
```

Note: this code is not tested and handwritten

Comment: @Junaid-Thanks for your reply.And No problem I will look int that!You gave me start and thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery.
on buttons clientclick add

{

$("#weburl").attr('href',($("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID>%">.val());
}